# Resetting the look and feel (appearance) of macOS operating system

Tags: mac, finder

Does anyone know how to change the appearance of macOS back to normal?

I recently had a computer repair and it appears that my machine now has hard edges on the icons and fields. Here is how it looked before:
[image]

Here is how it looks now with keylines on the edges of the icons. It looks bad. Please note this appearance is in all modal boxes associated with the Finder and within other apps.

Can anyone help find the correct setting to change this appearance back? In addition the red amber and green close buttons now have white icons in the middle when you hover over them rather than black ones.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "Increase Contrast" Accessibility setting:

```
System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Display > Increase Contrast
```

It seems your repair tech must have checked the box to switch it on.
Un-check the box to switch it back off.

Comment: Thats really good thank you so much.